# Pytorch cross entropy input dimensions

Tags: python, pytorch, python-3.7, cross-entropy, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to develop a binary classifier with Huggingface's BertModel and Pytorch. 
The classifier module is something like this:

```
class SSTClassifierModel(nn.Module):

  def __init__(self, num_classes = 2, hidden_size = 768):
    super(SSTClassifierModel, self).__init__()
    self.number_of_classes = num_classes
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.01)
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    self.classifier = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

  def forward(self, input_ids, att_masks,token_type_ids,  labels):
    _, embedding = self.bert(input_ids, token_type_ids, att_masks)
    output = self.classifier(self.dropout(embedding))
    return output
```

The way I train the model is as follows:

```
loss_function = BCELoss()
model.train()
for epoch in range(NO_OF_EPOCHS):
  for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
        input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
        input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
        token_type_ids = batch[2].to(device)
        labels = batch[3].to(device)
        # assuming batch size = 3, labels is something like:
        # tensor([[0],[1],[1]])
        model.zero_grad()        
        model_output = model(input_ids,  
                             input_mask, 
                             token_type_ids,
                             labels)
        # model output is something like: (with batch size = 3) 
        # tensor([[ 0.3566, -0.0333],
                 #[ 0.1154,  0.2842],
                 #[-0.0016,  0.3767]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward>)

        loss = loss_function(model_output.view(-1,2) , labels.view(-1))
```

I'm doing the `.view()`s because of the Huggingface's source code for `BertForSequenceClassification` [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/modeling_bert.html#BertForSequenceClassification) which uses the exact same way to compute the loss. But I get this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in binary_cross_entropy(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction)
   2068     if input.numel() != target.numel():
   2069         raise ValueError("Target and input must have the same number of elements. target nelement ({}) "
-> 2070                          "!= input nelement ({})".format(target.numel(), input.numel()))
   2071 
   2072     if weight is not None:

ValueError: Target and input must have the same number of elements. target nelement (3) != input nelement (6)
```

Is there something wrong with my labels? or my model's output? I'm really stuck here. The documentation for Pytorch's BCELoss says:

*Input: (N,∗) where ∗ means, any number of additional dimensions

Target: (N,∗), same shape as the input*

How should I make my labels the same shape as the model output? I feel like there's something huge that I'm missing but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few observations:

- The code that you refer to uses `CrossEntropyLoss` but you are using `BCELoss`.
- `CrossEntropyLoss` takes prediction logits (size: (N,D)) and target labels (size: (N,)) whereas `BCELoss` takes p(y=1|x) (size: (N,)) and target labels (size: (N,)) as p(y=0|x) can be computed from p(y=1|x)
- `CrossEntropyLoss` expects logits i.e whereas `BCELoss` expects probability value

Solution:

Since you pass an (N,2) tensor, it gives an error. You only need to pass p(y=1|x), therefore you can do

`loss = loss_function(model_output.view(-1,2)[:,1] , labels.view(-1))`

above I assumed that the second value is p(y=1|x).

A cleaner way would be to make model output only one value i.e p(y=1|x) and pass it to the loss function. It seems from the code that you are passing logit values and not probability values, so you may also need to compute `sigmoid (model_output)` if you want to use `BCELoss` or alternatively you can use `BCEWithLogitsLoss`.

Another alternative is to change the loss to `CrossEntropyLoss` that should work too as it can work for binary labels too.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. Both solved my problem. Except that the output of my model is not p(y=1|x) and p(y=0|x) and I should use a softmax for that!

Comment: Yeah sorry, I realized a little late. I updated answer to reflect all three scenarios--- using CE, BCE and BCElogits loss